# ERT: should-error doesn't catch failed assertions

Tags: ert

Today I'm trying out ERT for the first time.

```
(should-error (/ 1 0))
```

This works and returns `(arith-error)` as expected.

```
(should-error (cl-assert nil))
```

The assertion escapes the `should-error` and causes a stack trace.

What's the appropriate thing to do if I want to test code that uses `cl-assert`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked this question on [gnu.emacs.help](https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/help-gnu-emacs) and learned how to make this work:

```
(let ((debug-on-error nil)) (should-error (cl-assert nil)))
```

It seems `cl-assert` doesn't raise an error if `debug-on-error` is true, it just goes straight to the debugger.